# Ajax in jquery, php isset cannot detect the value posted

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am asking for help with my code. I am trying to get values then send it to php script through ajax by jquery. I can get the values but I don't know what's wrong with it. Your help is appreciated :)

**Ajax**:

```
$(".Qty").submit(function(e){
    data_form = parseInt($(this).find(".buyQty").val());
    id = parseInt($(this).attr('name'));
    console.log("id :", id, "Quantity: ", data_form);
    $(this).find(".addCart").val('Adding...');
    $.ajax({
        url: "php/cart_process.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {'id': id, 'qty': data_form},
        success: function(data){
            $("#cart-info").html(data.items);
            $(".Qty").find(".addCart").val('Add to Cart'); 
            alert("Item added to Cart!");
            if($(".shopping-cart-box").css("display") == "block"){
                $(".cart-box").trigger( "click" );
            }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("some error");
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**php**:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['id'])){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        echo "<script>console.log('id received: " .$id. "' );</script>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: @JeramiahHarland I input something but the php script returned nothing

Answer (score 2):

Your php script isn't returning a JSON object like your JS expects. 
Your JS expects `data` to be a JSON object and you are trying to get the value in the index `items`. E.G `data.items`

Try this.

PHP

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['id'])){
        $output = array();
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $output['items'] = "<p>id received: {$id} </p>";

        echo json_encode($output);
    }
?>
```

JQuery

```
$(".Qty").submit(function(e){
    data_form = parseInt($(this).find(".buyQty").val());
    id = parseInt($(this).attr('name'));
    console.log("id :", id, "Quantity: ", data_form);
    $(this).find(".addCart").val('Adding...');
    $.ajax({
        url: "php/cart_process.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {'id': id, 'qty': data_form},
        success: function(data){
            console.log('raw data:');
            console.log(data);

            $("#cart-info").html(data.items);
            $(".Qty").find(".addCart").val('Add to Cart'); 
            alert("Item added to Cart!");
            if($(".shopping-cart-box").css("display") == "block"){
                $(".cart-box").trigger( "click" );
            }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("some error");
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: it worked, thanks! I thought I could echo the value with script tag ...

Comment: however, I would like to ask is the output expected to be something like this in console: {"items":"<p>id received: 1 <\/p>"}

Comment: @AgnesLeung like i said your script expects JSON and your PHP now outputs JSON. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp